# How to change box shadow to last two elements in DB flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I have a DB with some data, I display data on the screen using Stack widget so each element is on the top of another, I also have a box-shadow and if there are a lot of data than there are a lot of box-shadows and it looks awful, so I decided to show box-shadow only where id is equal to the last element's id and the previous one

```
if (taskID == data.length && taskID == data.length -1 ) {
          return [
            new BoxShadow(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(63, 54, 118, 0.21),
              blurRadius: 46.0,
              spreadRadius: 0.0,
            )
          ];
        } else {
          return [
            new BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.red,
              blurRadius: 46.0,
              spreadRadius: 0.0,
            )
          ];
        }
```

Comment: what's the problem with your current code?

Comment: @Ryosuke it does not work as I want to, it returns false, because for example the first statement is true but the second one is false,  9 == 9 true but 9 == 9-1 not true

Comment: oh didn't see that...use `taskID == data.length-1 || taskID == data.length -2`

Comment: @Ryosuke no it does not work, I need to return last and the previous element.

Comment: and as I know || means 'or' I need 'and'

Comment: @Rostyk: It seems your question does not have any connection to sqlite, please consider remove this tag.

Comment: you want to give the same `BoxShadow` to the last and second last item both... so it's correct.... but how are you putting these things in the stack? The problem must be there.. post more code